# Strange behavior in dictionary operation along with multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I am learning to use multiprocessing in Python. After doing some research, I come up with the following code, which creates two objects, the pool will run the job in parallel. The original code has many other codes so I simplify the as in the following prototype

```
import multiprocessing as mp
class GrandParent:
    _data = dict()

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self, num1, num2):
        assert (num1 in self._data) and (num2 in self._data)
        return self._data[num1] * 232 + self._data[num2] * 101

class Parent(GrandParent):
    def __init__(self):
        GrandParent.__init__(self)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
        self._data[0] = 20
        self._data[1] = 100
        self._data[2] = 300

def worker(args):
    obj, method, num1, num2 = args
    return getattr(obj, method)(num1, num2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Child()
    print(a._data)
    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    objList = [Child(), Child()]
    ML = ((obj, "run", id, 2) for id, obj in enumerate(objList))

    list_results = pool.map(worker, ML)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(list_results)
```

The code terminates at the pool with an error generated from the `assert (num1 in self._data) and (num2 in self._data)`, by tracing the code, I found that the `_data` is empty though it should be assigned with something before calling (see `__init__` in `Child`). Also, from the [python document](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), I think it should be ok to insert the key-value to the dict by using the square bracket directly, the output of the above code print all the `_data` correctly before the pool is called. It flushes out all the key-values in `_data` anyway, so I try to change to use `update` to insert key-value to the dictionary

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
        self._data.update({0: 20})
        self._data.update({1: 100}) 
        self._data.update({2: 300})
```

This time the code runs without error. It is strange behavior. Could someone help to explain why is it. Thanks

Comment: what are version is yr python & OS? mine is 3.8.3 & ubuntu. no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class GrandParent:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = dict()
...
```

fixes the problem.

Your `_data = dict()` created a static class member named `_data`, which you were repeatedly initializing each time you created an object.  But no objects are created on the server using `__init__`, so _data there was never initialized.

Comment: ah ... I think I get it now. I am quite new to Python, I find that the variables are defined in python when needed, which is quite different from what I know in other languages. Shall I still keep the declaration variables at the top of the class?

Comment: In python 3.8, you'd write: `_data: Dict[int,int]` at the top of the class, where `Dict` is imported from package `typing`.  In 3.9, you'd write `_data: dict[int,int]`.  Note that this doesn't assign a value to the variable; it is simply a hint that isn't enforced.